# Creating new datacenter with Datastax OpsCenter

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I'd like to enable vnodes on my cassandra cluster, which has an Analytics dc and a regular Cassandra dc. I am using OpsCenter 5.0.1 and DSE 4.5. My question is: how can I create a new dc with OpsCenter, with vnodes enabled, so I can transfer my data over from my existing dc's. I am following the instructions on this [page](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/configuration/configVnodesProduction_t.html), but surely I don't have to manually edit the config file on every node, to enable a new datacenter, right? Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately OpsCenter's automated provisioning doesn't currently support creating multi-dc clusters or adding data centers to existing clusters.  We know this is important functionality that's missing, and are working on making that available as soon as we can.